# adding foreign key to tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to do the following:

Select `course_id` and `userid_DI` as two different foreign keys in the table `course_users`.

The table `users` has the following: `userid_DI`, `Country`, `LoE_DI`, `YoB`, `Age`, `gender`

The table `course` has the following: `course_id`, `institution`, `course_number`, `course_term`, `Course_Short_Title`, `Course_Long_title`

The table `course_users` has the following: `course_id`, `userid_DI`, `registered`, `viewed`, `explored`, `grade`

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ALTER TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE course_users 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES course (course_id),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (userid_DI) REFERENCES users (userid_DI);
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, I used your code but I am getting the following error: error code 1822 failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'course_users_ibfk_1 in the referenced table.

Comment: You need an index on the `userid_DI` column in the `users` table. Normally a foreign key references the primary key of the table, so that should be automatic.